# How to acces remote environment in Squish?

Tags: python, squish

I'm working with Squish and Python 3.7.
I use Squish to remote test an AUT on another system. As long as I don't interact with external files, there is no problem, but now I have to check whether the AUT created a certain file. In general I know how to look for a file, but how do I look for a file on the remote system? The script only looks on my local system.

Comment: please go through this link may it will help you.

https://www.froglogic.com/blog/using-remote-system-api-start-aut-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'RemoteSystem' object will help you access environment variables as well as the file system on your remote testing system.

https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#RemoteSystem.getEnvironmentVariable-function